# Generate random numbers without repeat and sequence

Tags: php, laravel

I want to generate a random 4 digit pin without repeat and sequence numbers. I have tried the below code but it only preventing repeat numbers, it is still returning sequence numbers.

```
function randomGen($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}

$random = randomGen(1,9,4); 

$random_no = "";
foreach($random as $int){
 $random_no.=$int;   
}

$random_no = intval($random_no);
```

***expected output : 4759***

***Should not be like this 5537 and 7312***

Comment: Could you define what you mean by: _"repeat and sequence numbers"_? So in the 5534 is the 55 already a repeat and the 34 already a sequence? How about 5435? Is the 543 a sequence, and are the fives repeated?

Comment: This rule - if interpreted as KIKO says - will reduce the amount of combinations drastically, making them MUCH easier to predict (or get a lucky hit on trial&error). "Random" should really mean random.. you must not influence, or it isn't random anymore

Comment: @HonkderHase: I agree, this seems a bad idea. Rahumathulla is clearly ignoring my question and doesn't bother to define what (s)he wants, nor does (s)he give a reason for the restrictions. In this case four random digits seems to be the best answer.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware 543 is not a sequence in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This function should do what you're asking for:

```php
function generateRandomNumber($length = 4) {
    $number = '';
    $prev = '';

    while (strlen($number) < $length) {
        $digit = mt_rand(1, 9);

        if ($prev != $digit && $prev != $digit - 1) {
            $number .= $digit;
            $prev = $digit;
        }
    }

    return $number;
}
```

It uses a while loop checking each iteration if the string is already long enough.
If the last character is not the same as the one we're generating this iteration, which excludes any double numbers, we can also check if the last is not equal to the current - 1 which excludes any sequences of numbers.